# New field for Azure index

Tags: azure-search

I have Sitecore 9.3 with Azure PAAS and are using Azure search.

I added one 'shared' field to the media templates of the checkbox type with name **IsOptimized**.
I added the following entry to the config.
I just want to filter data on the basis of it.

```
<field fieldName="isoptimized"       cloudFieldName="isoptimized_b"    searchable="NO"   retrievable="YES"  facetable="YES"  filterable="YES"  sortable="YES"  boost="1f" type="System.Boolean"  settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure" />
```

I also made an entry for the same under Fields under the index.
I indexed the item when the checkbox is selected and when the checkbox is not selected.
But in both the scenarios, I am getting the item in the Azure search but not the field with the correct value.

We do have certain fields like **created by** indexed in it for the item.

Am I missing something silly?

**Edit 1**:

Adding the snapshot from Azure search where I have mapped the field.

[image]

Presently, even if the checkbox is selected, I am getting null for that item.
I am just checking the item by its id and checking all the fields on the Azure portal itself.

Comment: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2020/09/11/using-full-lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search/

Comment: @MarkCassidy: Thanks for the link will go through it and update here.

Comment: @MarkCassidy: Thanks for the article. I went through it. Unfortunately, I couldn't identify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the field `indexed`. I was missing the entry in the following section of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`:

[image]